# Comparing date in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails app, I get some date strings like `'2016-6'`, `'2016-10'` and I want to find the latest one, how to do it?

Comment: very strange date format)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parse specific date format by using [Date.strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime):

```
str = '2016-6'
Date.strptime(str, '%Y-%m')
=> Wed, 01 Jun 2016
```

Then you can simply compare dates:

```
Date.strptime('2016-6', '%Y-%m') < Date.strptime('2016-10', '%Y-%m')
=> true
```

And find a string, which represents the last date:

```
['2016-6', '2016-10'].max_by { |str| Date.strptime(str, '%Y-%m')  }
=> "2016-10"
```

Comment: It is totally what I want! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your getting your dates from a from you might want to use something like this to format your date:

```
<%= f.date_select :startdate,{ discard_day: false, discard_month: true, discard_year: true }, { :class => 'form-control' } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The date format provided is insufficient to do parsing.

Ruby can parse string dates so long as the format complies with certain rules.

While using hyphens `-`, inclusion of a day is mandatory.

This is because typically hyphenated date formats include the day.

Fortunately, if you're willing or able to change the format you can do the following:

```
date = '2016/6'
DateTime.parse(date)
=> Wed, 01 Jun 2016 00:00:00 +0000
```

Otherwise I would just append the first to your dates.

```
date = '2016-6' + '-1'
DateTime.parse(date)
 => Wed, 01 Jun 2016 00:00:00 +0000
```

Now you can do typical comparison stuff:

```
date1 = ...
date2 = ...
case date1 <=> date2
when -1
  # date1 is before date2
when 1
  # date1 is after date2
when 0
  # date1 is equal to date2
```